# swift - Renaming project after it is on TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, rename, testflight

I have a project on TestFlight and I tried renaming it using the steps from this video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRnVjtNLLLk

After archiving and trying to upload this to the test center I am getting the error:

Missing IOS distribution signing identity for Name. Xcode can request one for you.

This app uses the Icloud. I'm not sure if I have to change anything there or not. I have tried using the old tables(old name of project) and the new tables(new name of project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the Apple WWDRCA expired two days ago. (Feb 14, 2016): https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

1. Open **Keychain Access**, and in the menu,
2. Click **View -> Show Expired Certificates**.
3. Delete the expired Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate

Authority from both the login and System Keychains. Install the renewed certificate from Apple by downloading from https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

then opening it.

Also you will need to do restart Xcode to reflects the changes -> Clean your project -> Build then try again to generate your archive. Ref:

Thanks.

Comment: @Grumpy, Its not issue of renaming, its issue as I explained. Just do these steps, it will archive and upload build properly. Thanks.

Comment: I have opened keychain access but cannot find View-> Show expired Certificates. At the top is says that this certificate has an invalid user.

Comment: did you find it, is it running @Grumpy, Actually you have to search or see whole of LOGIN and SYSTEM in your KEYCHAIN.

Comment: It's running and uploaded. There was one problem renaming the file. It seemed to rename everything inside the code but the old name still exists. I need to change it in a couple more places I think.